# What is the default background color of the navigation bar in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationbar

I would like to set the background color of a menu to that of the navigation bar. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The default navbar color in iOS 7 is `[UIColor colorWithRed:(247.0f/255.0f) green:(247.0f/255.0f) blue:(247.0f/255.0f) alpha:1];`

Comment: Do you mean : 

[UIColor colorWithRed:(247.0f/255) green:(247.0f/255) blue:(247.0f/255) alpha:1]

Comment: @gran_profaci there is no difference between your code and my code ;-) f just tells the compiler that this number is a float.

Comment: Can you explain how do you know it ?

Comment: @lapin Just take a screenshot and found it with color picker in Photoshop. :-)

Comment: Since `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` expects floats it should be `255.0f` instead of `255.0`. The later one is double and results in a compiler warning because of implicit casting. `[UIColor colorWithRed:(247.0f/255.0f) green:(247.0f/255.0f) blue:(247.0f/255.0f) alpha:1];`

Comment: Is there any way to get this programmatically in case Apple decides to change this in the future?

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5**

Nav bar color in light appearance:

```
UIColor(red: 0.969, green: 0.969, blue: 0.969, alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the tint color of a navigation bar, do this:

```
[aNavbar barTintColor]
```

By using this when you set the background color of your menu, you will not have to change it in case you change your navigation bar tint.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

I am not sure the color does not change from version to version. In my app I use this:

```
var navBarDefaultColor: UIColor?

// save:
navBarDefaultColor = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor

//restore:
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = navBarDefaultColor!
```

Comment: For my case it was backgroundColor.

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift**, it is:

```
UIColor(colorLiteralRed: (247/255), green: (247/255), blue: (247/255), alpha: 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0 +**

`UIColor(red: (247/255), green: (247/255), blue: (247/255), alpha: 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `barTintColor` to `nil` to restore to the default white color.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5:** 
UINavigationBar Default barTintColor for Light Mode.

```
#colorLiteral(red: 0.9763854146, green: 0.9765252471, blue: 0.9763546586, alpha: 1)
```